# Using grep and logical operators for pattern matching within shell script

Tags: shell-script, shell, grep, scripting, dig

Im trying to develop a script that finds a specific pattern in the output of the dig command running against a list of domains. To do this I'm using grep but  having difficulty implementing this using multiple logical operations.

I want to achieve something like this:

```
if output contains ("NXDOMAIN") and ("test1.com" or "test2.com"); then
echo output;
```

I have managed to get it working for the pattern `"NXDOMAIN"` by piping the output into grep but I am lost on how to implement the logical operators. My script so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
input="/root/subdomains.txt"
while IFS= read -r line
do
    output=$(dig "$line")
    if echo "$output" | grep "NXDOMAIN" >&/dev/null; then
        echo "$output";
    else
        echo " " >&/dev/null;
    fi
done < "$input"
```

Is using grep the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for `grep` or `bash` here.

```
#!/bin/sh -
input="/root/subdomains.txt"

contains() {
  case "$1" in
    (*"$2"*) true;;
    (*) false;;
  esac
}

while IFS= read <&3 -r line
do
    output=$(dig "$line")
    if
      contains "$output" NXDOMAIN && {
        contains "$output" test1.com || contains "$output" test2.com
      }
    then
      printf '%s\n' "$output"
    fi
done 3< "$input"
```

If you really wanted to use `grep`, you'd define `contains` as:

```
contains() {
  printf '%s\n' "$1" | grep -qFe "$2"
}
```

But that would be less efficient as it means spawning two extra processes and in most `sh` implementation executing an external `grep` utility.

Or:

```
#!/bin/sh -
input="/root/subdomains.txt"

match() {
  case "$1" in
    ($2) true;;
    (*) false;;
  esac
}

while IFS= read <&3 -r line
do
    output=$(dig "$line")
    if
      match "$output" '*NXDOMAIN*' &&
        match "$output" '*test[12].com*'
    then
      printf '%s\n' "$output"
    fi
done 3< "$input"
```

Or do without the intermediary function:

```
#!/bin/sh -
input="/root/subdomains.txt"

while IFS= read <&3 -r line
do
    output=$(dig "$line")
    case $output in
      (NXDOMAIN)
        case $output in
          (test1.com | test2.com) printf '%s\n' "$output"
        esac
    esac
done 3< "$input"
```

That would also work with `bash`, but there's no need to add a dependency to `bash` when your (presumably faster and leaner) standard `sh` can do it.

Comment: thank you for the detailed answer. "match" seemed to do the trick for me

Answer (score 0):

You can create a logical `AND` by piping into grep again, and a logical `OR` using regular expressions:

```
echo "$output" | grep "NXDOMAIN" | grep -E 'test1\.com|test2\.com'
```

Comment: `grep -E "[test1.com|test2.com]"` looks for any single character in the set `t` `e` `s` `1` `.` `c` `o` `m` `|` `2`. You'd need `grep -E 'test1\.com|test2\.com'` or `grep 'test[12]\.com'` to look for either `test1.com` or `test2.com`

Comment: That approach only works if the NXDOMAIN and `test[12].com` are on the same line.